# jQuery как обратиться к динамическому дочернему элементу

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Не знаю как обратиться к только одному из дочерних элементов класса, созданных динамически. (когда нажимаешь, например, на 5ый элемент, то в консоль выводиться 5 раз), вот пример кода:

```js
$('#next').click(function()
{
 var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
 var html = '<div>'+rnd+'</div>';
 $(html).attr('id', rnd).addClass('order').prependTo('#orders');
 console.log(rnd);
  
  $('.order').click(function()  //тут проблема
{
 console.log($(this).attr('id')); 
});
  
});
```

```css
.order {
 display: block;
 padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='next'>More</button>
<div id='orders'>
 <div class='order'>Y</div>
 <div class='order'>X</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы вызываете метод .click() внутри уже существующего метода .click(), получается рекурсивный вызов функции. Чтобы этого не происходило, нужно вынести второй целевой клик за рамки первой функции, так будет работать:

```js
$('#next').click(function()
{
 var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
 var html = '<div>'+rnd+'</div>';
 $(html).attr('id', rnd).addClass('order').prependTo('#orders');
 console.log(rnd);
  
});

  $('body').on('click', '.order', function()  //тут нет проблемы
{
 console.log($(this).attr('id')); 
});
```

```css
.order {
 display: block;
 padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='next'>More</button>
<div id='orders'>
 <div class='order'>Y</div>
 <div class='order'>X</div>
</div>
```